# A factor column used for Hive Partitioning in write_dataset() becomes a chr column in open_dataset()

Tags: r, apache-arrow

In my R code, my data has an Id column which it stores as a `factor` (its values are a combination of characters and digits), and this works well.

I am storing data in an arrow dataset that is being partitioned by the Id column, which works naturally as my data is processed one Id at a time.

When I then read back the data from the arrow dataset, the Id column is converted to a `character` column in R.

Is there a way to continue using the Id column for the partitioning but have it automatically converted back to a factor?

If not, is there a most efficient way to convert it back to a factor "manually" upon reading the data?

Demo:

```
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

idFactor <- factor(c(
  rep("A12-E123-I1234", 100),
  rep("B34-F456-J5678", 200),
  rep("C56-G789-K9101", 300),
  rep("D78-H101-L1121", 400)
))

factorData <- data.table(Id = idFactor, FactorId = idFactor)
testCols <- paste0("Column", seq(1, 2))
for (j in testCols) {
  set(factorData, j = j, value = runif(nrow(factorData), 0, 100000))
}

write_dataset(factorData, "factor_dataset", format = "parquet", partitioning = "Id", hive_style = TRUE)
ds <- open_dataset("factor_dataset")
blah <- ds %>% collect()

ds$schema # The schema shows Id as a string, and FactorId as a dictionary as expected.
str(blah) # str() indicates Id as chr, FactorId as Factor
```

Comment: This also happens when the index is class `integer` or `Date`. I don't know of a way to work around it, unfortunately, I'll be following this in case somebody knows of a solution or workaround (other than calling `factor` each time).

Comment: As for converting it back to `factor`, is there a reason you can't do `... %>% collect() %>% mutate(id = factor(id))`?

Comment: I am a dplyr newb: up until now I have been doing most of my data manipulations via data.table() operations, but that looks like something I could try.

In doing that I'll end up with different levels on the factor depending on the query; I'm still trying to figure out how important/dangerous that would be.

Comment: At this point I am wondering if having an extra column in the data that is identical to the Id column makes sense.  Not great for wasting space, but then maintains the whole factor with all its values/levels.

Comment: I think you've identified the core deficiency of converting `id` on the fly from arrow partitioning: the `levels=` of the factor. Granted, `levels(rbind(data.frame(a=factor("a")), data.frame(a=factor("b")))$a)` returns `c("a","b")`, combining levels as one might want, so it is still functional, but if you're hoping for context outside of that which is loaded in the current filtered arrow query, you will need to do one of the hacks. Having said that ... in all but rare situations, I tend to trust better assigning the levels of a factor _after_ loading. Context-specific, but my two cents.

Comment: I am thinking that perhaps I could save the full factor type in a simple RDS file or something, and use it to re-cast the Id column after loading.

Comment: While that would work, whether `.rds` is better than `.parquet` depends on your use. For me, it is useful to be able to have lazy filters, loading only portions of the data, and the fact that it is cross-platform is a bonus, though I have not yet capitalized on that. Parquet files are fairly efficient space-wise, so while I don't know what will truly be smaller, consider the tradeoff of always loading all data instead of loading a portion as needed. (There are likely other benefits, I'm reducing to just a couple.)

Comment: Interesting that you brought the pros and cons up!  I am actually in the process of transitioning from rds to parquet, as our projects have grown, and we are at the point where our data is big enough that being able to load portions of rows/columns has become required.